# tmux reattach to session automatically after kill and restart

Tags: tmux, console, session

I have a tmux session, in which i have a running node.js server. Because i'd like to watch the colored console outputs as they are printed, i always attach myself to the session. So far, so good. It get's a bit annoying then the tmux session gets killed and restarted from outside. This happens automatically by a gitlab-ci script, which is triggered by new commits on the GitLab project.

At the moment i always have to reattach myself to that session manually. Is there a way to wait after the kill and reattach as soon as the session gets restarted wihtout doing anything manually?

(If not, is there a way to view the colored console outputs without being attached? My only solution at the moment is to tail on a logfile, but sadly without the colored lines, which help to see errors in realtime.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following?

```
while :; do tmux attach || tmux new; sleep 1; done
```

Comment: This works! The new session or clause is not needed in my case (because Gitlab always starts it), but the idea with the while loop is great - Thanks!